# vuejs middleware first page load

Tags: vue.js, middleware, vue-router

I want to redirect the user if he is not logged in via middleware (The current user is first loaded from localstorage)

auth.js

```
export default async function ({ store, redirect }) {

        if(!store.state.stateLoaded) {
            await store.dispatch('loadState')
        }

        if (!store.state.user) {
            redirect('login')
        }
    }
}
```

This works fine when I navigate between routes, but not when I initially load the page.